# html image moves when zoomed in

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar with a few images as the navigation buttons and when I zoom to 110% on chrome (only) the right image falls out of the nav bar. It is for a school project.

Here is the HTML for the nav bar as well as the CSS.

**CSS**

```
nav {
    width: 960px;
    height: 54px;
    background-color: #191a19;
    margin: auto;
}

.menu_button {
    border: 2px solid #19242e;
}

.menu_button:hover  {
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

[html](http://pastebin.com/tRxCQRKy)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themohanahuja/JvLjG/)

Comment: the link to the css and html would be much more helpfull if it was a jsfiddle

Comment: CSS and HTML [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5p4tU/). Always provide jsfiddle.

Comment: increase the width of nav, or make the nav fluid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change either the width of your nav css element to a higher number (965px) or lower your .menu_button class' border to 1px;

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the 1px does change the look but I don't mind it. But do you know how to center the images because previously they were taking up the whole width

Comment: You could use something like this:
nav>a:nth-child(1)>img  {
  margin-left:2px;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
nav {
    width: 960px;
    height: 54px;
    background-color: #191a19;
    margin: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.menu_button {
    border: 2px solid #19242e;
}

.menu_button:hover  {
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
}

nav a{
    display:block
    width:233;
    float:left;
    height:50;
}

nav img{
    width:233;
    height:50;

}
</style>

    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">
            <img class="menu_button" src="images/home_button.jpg"  alt="home button">
        </a>
        <a href="overview.html">
            <img class="menu_button" src="images/overview_button.jpg"  alt="overview button">
        </a>
        <a href="tools.html">
            <img class="menu_button" src="images/tools_button.jpg"  alt="tools button">
        </a>
        <a href="tutorials.html">
            <img class="menu_button" src="images/tutorials_button.jpg"  alt="tutorials button">
        </a>
    </nav>
```

try this one dude, please vote for my answer so that i can help you again in the future. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help but that doesn't work, just tested